# Converting Eigen Allocator Vector to a standard STL vector

Tags: c++, eigen

I have the following data type:

```
std::vector<PointT, Eigen::aligned_allocator<PointT> > points;
```

I need to be able to convert this to a

```
std::vector<PointT> points_converted;

points_converted = std::vector<pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal>(points.size());
for(int i=0; i<points_converted.size(); i++) points_converted[i] = points[i];
```

Currently, I am looping through points and copying it over to a preinitialized points_converted. It is too slow as there are a million objects in that vector. I would prefer to somehow "cast" it. Is this possible?

Comment: *It is too slow* -- How slow is "too slow"?  Second, are you running an optimized build and not a "debug" or unoptimized build?  And please show us the code that currently copies.

Comment: Also is PointT a POD?

Comment: updated. well..it takes like 0.01s which.

Comment: Still no information on whether you are running an optimized build or not.  And copying a million items takes 1/100 of a second.  Is this really a bottleneck?  Last, note that your loop uses `=`.  This implies that a user-defined assignment operator is invoked to properly copy a point from source to destination.  Thus casting wouldn't even be recommended (if it could be done) since the objects must be copied correctly.  Last, the STL way to do this instead of a `for` loop is `std::transform`.

Comment: yes..i am building a system that has to run at almost 30hz on a gpu

Comment: Hi!
I know this is quite old, but did you find a solution? :)